# Does a BLDC stator benefit of being i one piece?

Tags: electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor, stator

Does a stator benefit of being in one piece, as different phases may form a horse-shoe(?), or is the layout puerly of manufacturing efficency?

Comment: The stator of a BLDC creates a flux circuit. The nature of this flux circuit is an important factor in motor performance. However, a flux circuit need not be a single piece. In fact, usually the stator is built up from laminations, similar to a transformer core. At least in my limited experience.

Comment: @mkeith, thanks. I'm aware of that, and the purpose of lamination.  I'm about to hack an existing motor into a strange acctuator and thus need to break the stator apart and rebuild coils into a straight line. I know there's a hundred reasons not to, but I'd still like an answer to the question.

Comment: You better rephrase or elaborate on the question. Because I can't tell what you are really asking. The flux circuit has to remain intact. Apart from that, it does not matter if the stator is one piece or not. Don't forget to consider the mechanical force exerted between the stator and rotor. If you hack the stator, make sure you maintain enough mechanical strength in it so that it can withstand the force. FYI, you can buy linear motors. In case you want to save yourself some hacking. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motor

Answer (score 2):

> Does a stator benefit of being in one piece, as different phases may
>   form a horse-shoe(?)

Yes. The 'horseshoe' is required to complete the magnetic circuit. The plot below is a simulation of magnetic flux in an 'inrunner' BLDC motor (outrunners are similar except the rotor is on the outside and stator in the middle). Flux density is indicated by color (red = high, green = low). You can see the lines of flux going around the horseshoe formed by adjacent stator arms and the outer ring of the stator.

Without this 'horseshoe' the flux would have to go through air and/or other non-magnetic materials to get from one stator arm to the next. The [magnetic reluctance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance) of air is much higher than silicon steel, so the flux density would be much weaker and the motor would have less torque.

[image]

Theoretically you could cut the stator apart between each arm and rejoin it in a straight line to make a linear motor, but in practice it would be very difficult. The pieces would have to be shaped and butted together with no air gaps. Silicon steel is very hard to work, and the coils are delicate.

You could remove the windings and separate the stator laminations, then cut them to the shapes you need, but it would be easier to just have new laminations stamped or buy a ready-made linear motor.